# Multiple nested excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this excel situation:

C2 = "A", D2= "A", set E2 = "A"

C2 = "B", D2 = "B", set E2 = "B"

C2= "B", D2= "A", set E2 = "A"

and....

How can I write such nested formulas for column E to be populated from values of same row column C and D?

We have a 5x5 value table. So if col = "X" and row = "Y" result should be "Z". I need to lookup this table and set value automatically with formula

Please advise

Comment: How many situations are we talking 3, 4 ,20..?

Comment: Generally speaking, in E2, you can do `=If(And(C2="A",D2="A"),"A",if(And(C2="B",D2="B"),"B",...)`. but it looks like you have lots of these. A `Vlookup()` table might work too. Can you expand on your problem a little more?

Comment: @ScottCraner, at most 12 situtations

Comment: @BruceWayne, updated the question. I tried the sample you sent it didn't work

Comment: Then as @BruceWayne just stated it would probably be better if you made a table with all the possible combinations and the desire output then use a vlookup or INDEX/MATCH.  Nesting an indeterminate amount of IFs is a little daunting.

Comment: Is your updated info. right? You have if `E2 = "A"` in the case that C2 is B or A, and D2 is A.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually have the values in a 2d table something like this (in a sheet called Lookup say):-

[image]

then you can use the table to get the values.

Either using row and column headers:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Lookup!$B$2:$F$6,MATCH(C2,Lookup!$A$2:$A$6,0),MATCH(D2,Lookup!$B$1:$F$1,0)),"")
```

or just using the position of the letters in a string:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Lookup!$B$2:$F$6,FIND(C2,"ABCDE"),FIND(D2,"ABCDE")),"")
```

[image]